# Python / Django - Local variable designed before assignment

Tags: python, django

I know this topic is talked many times in Stackoverflow but it concerns many different methods and I need help. I'm stuck since four hours ^^'

Here is the message : **local variable 'menuItem' referenced before assignment**

```
def B2BpartnerMenuDetailModify(request, partnerId, menuId, menuItemId):
message = ''
e = B2BpartnerUser(request, partnerId)
try:
    menuDetail = Menu.objects.get(id=menuId)
except Menu.DoesNotExist:
    return logoutUser(request)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = MenuDetailForm(request.POST, mySelf=partnerId)
    if form.is_valid():
        descrShort = form.cleaned_data['descrShort']
        paragraph = form.cleaned_data['paragraph']
        producteur = form.cleaned_data['producteur']
        position = MenuItem.objects.filter(menuId = menuDetail).filter(paragraph = paragraph).count() + 1
        menuItem = MenuItem(menuId = menuDetail)
        menuItem.descrShort = descrShort
        menuItem.paragraph = paragraph
        menuItem.producteur = producteur
        menuItem.save()
        if producteur > 0:
            menuItemProd = MenuItemProd(menuItemId = menuItem)
            menuItemProd.entrepriseId = producteur
            menuItemProd.save()
        message = _('Details modified successfuly')
else:
    data = {'descrShort': menuItem.descrShort, 'paragraph': menuItem.paragraph, 'producteur': menuItem.producteur}
    form = MenuDetailForm(initial=data)
menuItems = MenuItem.objects.filter(menuId = menuDetail).select_related()
menus = Menu.objects.filter(entrepriseId=e)
menuParagraph = MenuParagraph.objects.filter(actif=1)
modifier = True
#detail = False
return render (request, 'front/B2Bmenu.html', {'MenuDetailForm': form, 'menus': menus, 'message': message, 'partnerId': partnerId, 'modifier': modifier, 'detail': detail, 'menuDetail': menuDetail, 'menuParagraph': menuParagraph, 'menuId': menuId, 'menuItems': menuItems})
```

I'm sure I can get my page when this error is resolved. I'm sure it's a little error, I'm a beginner at Python but I love the language :)

If you want I can give you more details but I don't think it's necessary ^^

Have a nice day and thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your `else` block is accessing `menuItem` which is only defined in the `if` block. How are you expecting this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it !

I just forgot to add another try for this variable, just after the first try.

```
try:
    menuItem = MenuItem.objects.get(id=menuItemId)
except MenuItem.DoesNotExist:
    return logoutUser(request)
```